# Best word or phrasing to describe the link between an object and a process

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to describe a relationship between an object and a process.  Once the object crosses a certain point, a process takes place 100% of the time.

An example: whether a person jumps or is pushed off a building they fall.  Gravity does not care how the person became airborne.

What is the phrase or word to describe gravity's relationship with how the person became airborne?

It doesn't care.  There's no relationship. It just does.

Help!

Comment: I would go with "omnipresent" if referring to gravity. To be accurate though gravity is acting on you 100% of the time anyhow, no matter activity or process you're undergoing. Your question is somewhat poorly phrased. Could you ask it again in other words?

Comment: A relationship in which a definite outcome is absolutely determined by a given output in maths is called a _function_ or _mapping_ (but for once, terminology isn't standard) and the relationship a _functional_ one.

Comment: Are you looking for a noun, adjective, verb? Can you give an example of how you would like to use the coveted word/phrase?

Comment: It seems to me that gravity is a (static, in the computer sense) part of the *environment*.

Comment: It feels like the concept of *determinism* comes into play, but it would be helpful to see a sample sentence to get an idea of how you intend to use the word.

Comment: @Ben Is "causality" the term you're looking for? http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/causality

Comment: Intrinsic. That would describe what gravity is to someone who is falling regardless of how they got there.

Answer (score 1):

*Inexorable* (["not able to be stopped or changed"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inexorable)) could describe the relationship between an object and something that always happens to that object under certain conditions.

Or perhaps *implacable* ("[not capable of being appeased, significantly changed, or mitigated"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/implacable)) if the process has an associated element of consciousness, e.g. not caring.

Comment: Nice answer: succinct yet complete. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You asked "What is the phrase or word to describe gravity's relationship with how the person became airborne?"

I would say that gravity was ***indifferent*** to how the person became airborne and ***indiscriminately*** acted on him.